# How do you count the variable changing in iteration of 1's

Tags: iteration

"value" can only either be 0, 60, 120, 180, 240 or 300. 
When I try to count each change that "value" has using iterations I'm not getting values of +1. It gives values which are stepping by 10000. Also I do not wish to iterate when a value is reached, I only wish to iterate when it has changed one of the 6 values.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int angles; 
int counter[6] = {0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300};  
if (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 0) 
    { 
        value = 0; 
    }
    if (a == 1 && b == 0 && c == 0) 
    {
        value = 60;
    }
    if (a == 1 && b == 0 && c == 1) 
    {
        value = 120;
    }
    if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 1) 
    {
        value = 180;
    }
    if (a== 0 && b == 1 && c == 1) 
    {
        value= 240;
    }
    if (a == 0 && b == 1 && c == 0) 
    {
        value = 300;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

2**3 == 8

You are missing conditions for some of the possible combinations of values.

I would put the conditions into a function and return the desired value as soon as it has been determined because that allows to sort out the conditions.  Doing that, you will inevitably notice that you do not know what to return in some cases.

Other than that, it´s not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Something like this:

```
#define ERROR -1
int get_value(int a, int b, int c)
{
        if(a)
        {
                if(b)
                {
                        return c ? ERROR : 0;
                }
                else
                {
                        return c ? 60 : 120;
                }
        }
        else
        {
                if(b)
                {
                        return c ? 240 : 300;
                }
                else
                {
                        return c ? 180 : ERROR;
                }
        }

        return ERROR;
}
```

I would probably avoid all this, consider each of the three values as one bit and use bit operators to get to the desired value.

Comment: There are only 6 states that a, b and c can be in. There are no conditions missing on the combinations of values as I am reading the values from a hall effect sensor. No other states exist.

Comment: In that case, you would never see the value of ERROR returned by the example function unless an error occurred, which might be fine for your purpose.  Do you mean to count how often any one of the possible values is being returned by the example function?